# drawing an oval in a fluid motion simply stops

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm currently writing code for a connect-four game using tkinter. I've managed to create a fluid movement of circles to simulate a disc-like feature. Unfortunately, the drawing of the circle stops midway (I believe due to the after command). Here is my code:

```py
def game_loop(player_1, player_2, guii, game):
    if game.get_current_player() == 1:  # PLAYER 1
        player = player_1
        current = 1
    else:
        player = player_2
        current = 2
    if isinstance(player, Ai) and current == 1:
        # the Ai finds a move, irrelevant to the problem. Lets assume the move is column #2 (so, the number will be 1)
        self.draw_circle(1)

    guii.return_root().after(100, game_loop, player_1, player_2, guii, game)# game_loop(player_1, player_2, guii, game))
    guii.mainloop()
```

The function plays for the AI if its his turn. a turn is added ONLY once a circle is FINISHED drawing - meaning, it hit the floor. So, while the human is thinking about his turn, or the circle is still drawing - the AI is unable to play.

and this is the function that moves the ovals:

```
## self.NUM_ROWS = 6
def smooth_motion(self, column, x_1, x_2, color):
    target_location = [x_1-100, 100 * (self.NUM_ROWS-1),
                       x_2-100, 100 * (self.NUM_ROWS-1) -100]
    while self.__canvas.coords(self.__disc) <= target_location:
        if color == "red":
            print(self.__canvas.coords(self.__disc))
        self.__canvas.update()
        coords_list = self.__canvas.coords(self.__disc)
        y_1 = coords_list[1]
        y_2 = coords_list[3]
        new_disc = self.__canvas.create_oval(x_1, y_1+0.85, x_2, y_2+0.85, fill=color)
        self.__canvas.delete(self.__disc)
        self.__disc = new_disc
```

When I was testing the GUI separately, it worked flawlessly. That is why I am SURE the problem is the .after() command. I can sample more code but I don't want to dump all of it as that wont be efficient, but, anything anyone needs will gladly be posted. Thank you for your input.

How the circle is calculated:

```
def draw_circle(self, column):
    x_1 = 100 + (column * 100)
    x_2 = column * 100
    if self.game.get_turn() % 2 == 0:
        disc = self.__canvas.create_oval(100 + (column * 100), 0, column * 100,
                                     self.NUM_ROWS - self.col_dict[column] - 1 * 100,
                                     fill='yellow')
        color = "yellow"
    else:  # colors the discs accordingly
        disc = self.__canvas.create_oval(100 + (column * 100), 0, column * 100,
                                     self.NUM_ROWS - self.col_dict[column] - 1 * 100,
                                     fill='red')
        color = "red"
    self.__disc = disc
    self.col_dict[column] += 1
    self.smooth_motion(column, x_1, x_2, color)
```

The columns are from 0-6. col_dict[column] starts as 0, 1 is added each time a ball is dropped in the column. I encounter this problem from the start, so it may be substituted for 0
game_binder simply calculates the circle and sends it to smooth_motion.

Comment: We don't need all the code, but we do need enough code to reproduce the problem. See [mcve] for tips on how to create a minimal example.

Comment: Thanks for looking. I've edited the OP, Looks like its enough

Comment: No, it's not. The indentation is broken and there are a lot of missing details. Please try to create a small, complete, and minimal example.

Comment: Thanks again! This is as smallest as I could get it

Comment: I don't mean to be argumentative, but let us take a look at what you've posted. There's an if block that deals with two players. Do you need both players to illustrate the problem with moving a single oval?  Also, these are methods in a class, but nowhere do you define the class. Finally, `game_loop` uses `self` but never defines what `self` is. To make a proper [mcve] we should be able to cut and paste a dozen or two lines of code and make it run.  The harder you make it for us to reproduce your problem, the less likely it is that anyone will answer you.